# upstart-udev-bridge is using 100% CPU (and a known fix doesn't help)

Tags: linux-mint, udev, laptop, upstart

I'm running Linux Mint 12 on a Latitude D630 and every time I start my laptop (and sometimes when I come back from being suspended), `top` shows that `upstart-udev-bridge` is using 100% CPU (and if I do nothing about it, the fan starts running at full and eventually it would presumably overheat).

I can stop it with `sudo stop upstart-udev-bridge` but I don't want to have to do that every time I start up.

I tried [this fix](http://areyoueye.net/?p=143)
(which so far as I can tell works for everyone else who's had this problem), but it didn't seem to do anything. The problem's still there.

Comment: Are you positive that installing the fixed package worked?

Comment: No I'm not. I just installed Linux Mint, and it seems to be ignoring some updates, but I don't really understand it.  When I run sudo apt-get update, I see

Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en

and

Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en_US

which I guess means some updates are being ignored, but I don't know how to fix that